# Intercepting SimpleCursorAdapter Action

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I am writing an application which is using a SimpleCursorAdapter to display a list of items from my SQLite Database. The application is a list application, which allows the user to create a list of items. There is a field in the database that keeps track of whether the user wants the list item's text crossed out or not.

Basically, I want to intercept the point in time where the SimpleCursorAdapter tries to settext() on my crossed_out field, and instead call a function to set the text of another field to strikethrough.

Is this possible without writing my own CursorAdapter? If not how can I go about writing my own CursorAdapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible without writing my own CursorAdapter?

You can attach a `ViewBinder` using [`setViewBinder()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#setViewBinder%28android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder%29), and implement a `ViewBinder` to format your `TextViews` as you wish.

> If not how can I go about writing my own CursorAdapter?

Step #1: Create a subclass of `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Step #2: Override [`setViewText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#setViewText%28android.widget.TextView,%20java.lang.String%29) and apply your formatting at that point, or override `bindView()` and fill in all of the row widgets yourself